# how can build basics bootstrap responsive layout for the link that i mentioned below

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I want make this layout with bootstrap responsive design  i am new with bootstrap can you help me for basic to layout with grid system please .

http://www.myhotels24.eu/fibe.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here's the link
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html

try to understand grid system and classes like col-lg-* ,col-md-* 
hope this ll help u out

Comment: i need the col- size for this site how can i make it saw the refrence  but not understand well